# Is the Haber Process here proceeding at positive Gibbs free energy change?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

$\ce{3H2 + N2 -> 2NH3}$ is the forward reaction used in the Haber process, the industrial production of ammonia. After studying Gibbs energy and how it is just another way of saying that the 2nd law of thermodynamics is obeyed if $\Delta G < 0$, I decided to apply it to some common reactions that I know, just to confirm that my understanding of the topic is correct.

When applying it to the Haber process forward reaction, I worked out change in entropy to be $\pu{-199 
J K^{-1} mol^{-1}}$. The enthalpy change for the forward reaction is exothermic and has a value of $\pu{-92 kJ mol^{-1}}$. Looking up common reaction conditions for the Haber process, I found that a compromise temperature of $\pu{650K}$ is used.

Applying this to the Gibbs energy equation $-92 - 650(-199/1000)$, I calculated a positive change in Gibbs energy for the reaction of which had a value of $\pu{37.35 kJ mol^{-1}}$.

As a result of this, I am now quite confused as to how the forward reaction can be allowed to proceed by the 2nd law of thermodynamics at a temperature of $\pu{650K}$, and I was wondering where my understanding of the Gibbs energy and thermodynamics falls short. I need help to explain the pitfalls in my calculations, understanding or even whether there is another factor that I am not considering.

Comment: This source has it as -32.7 kJ/mole N2: http://surfguppy.com/thermodynamics/caluclate-gibbs-free-energy-nitrogen-and-hydrogen-to-create-ammonia/

Comment: Did you adjust the values for $\Delta H$ for the higher temperature?

Comment: @Gert That source uses 298K as the temperature which results in change in Gibbs energy being negative. However in industry, a higher compromise temperature of 650K is used for the forward reaction to achieve higher rates of reaction. At this higher compromise temperature, change in Gibbs energy is positive. I assumed that the value for ΔH does not change with temperature. I know that it does but I thought it would only be very negligible. https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/equilibria/haber.html This source takes ΔH = -92kJmol<sup>-1</sup> and states conditions used are 673K-723K.

Comment: Sure but did you adjust you $\Delta H$ values for the higher temperature that you use? Both your reagents and reaction products are now hotter. It makes a difference in the calc, not just $T\Delta S$. Just try it.

Comment: Right, I will look into the effect that the increased temperature has on the value of ΔH and try to find one for a temperature of 650K.

Comment: You need to do the same thing for the $\Delta S$.

Comment: Just because the change of standard free energy for a reaction is positive, that does not mean that the reaction will not go at all.  It just means that the equilibrium conversion will be low.

Answer (score 4):

It's all about the pressure! The Haber process requires a pressure of about 200 atm. This is how the process becomes favorable, since LeChatelie's principle says that increasing pressure shifts toward the side with less moles of gas.

As long as Q is smaller than K, the reaction will go forward. For example, if nitrogen and hydrogen are supplied at stoichiometric ratio and 1% of a given reaction mixture is product, we would have the following partial pressures:

$$ P_\ce{N2} = 0.2475 \times \pu{200 atm}$$

$$ P_\ce{H2} = 0.7425 \times \pu{200 atm}$$

$$ P_\ce{NH3} = 0.01 \times \pu{200 atm}$$

Accordingly, Q would be

$$ Q = \frac{2^2}{50 \times 75^3} = \pu{1.9e-7} $$

In the Haber process, the concentration of product is kept small by continuously removing product (liquifying ammonia at low temperature) and feeding the remaining reactants back into the reaction mixture.

Comment: This is nice, could you expand on your explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The tendency of a reaction to proceed in a certain direction depends on the state of the concentration of each reactant. If you calculate the standard Gibbs free energy of the reaction and it's a positive number, that only means that - *if* the composition of the reaction medium corresponds to all components at standard concentration ($1 \ \textrm{mol/L}$) - then the reaction will shift in the reverse direction (to which you supposed when you calculated $\Delta G$).

I am not sure though if this is the case for the Haber Process as you presented.

It must be noted that often one will increase the temperature of a reaction in a way that is non-intuitive from a thermodynamic perspective: one might conclude that the reaction is being made less spontaneous in the desired reaction. However, in a practical setting, the kinetics are also important, that is, how fast the reaction proceeds towards equilibrium. A temperature increase will always increase the reaction rate, which may get us to an acceptable yield earlier, even if the maximum achievable yield (dictated by thermodynamics) will be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

the ΔH and ΔS don't change too much on temperature, but they change on pressure! when the pressure is 200 atm, the ΔH and ΔS are changed and the calculated ΔG is negative! I couldn't find the equation for ΔH and ΔS to P. But I check the results from Aspen Plus directly.